# Convert a 100-277V dimmer to 1-10V

Tags: led, dimmer

I'm trying to use the following dimmer:
https://www.smarthome.com/switchlinc-dimmer-insteon-2477dh-remote-control-dimmer-dual-band-high-wattage-white.html

with these lights

https://www.eledlights.com/led-lights/eled-indoor-lights/led-drop-ceiling-panel-lights.html

is there any product I can buy to fix the voltage issue and eliminate buzzing/flickering?

thanks!

Comment: ok so is there another stack exchange where I can post this question?

Comment: Try [Home Improvement StackExchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/). However, someone may call you out for asking the same question on different SE websites.

Comment: If this were viewed as a design issue , one can load the Triac with diode bridge to R:CR filter voltage divider using about 5 Watt load to scale and low pass filter to peak voltage  of 10V using 2RC=0.3 second  product

Comment: it is not possible to use that dimmer with that light fixture. You need a 0-10V dimmer - which is a completely different thing to what you have. The dimmer you have controls the power delivered to the light, while a 0-10V dimmer supplies a control signal to the light.

Answer (score 2):

From the manufacturer website.

0 -10V LED dimmer is required.

Recommendation: Lutron DVSTV

Comment: that's not a smart switch (does not work with wifi home automation)